# Is it possible to decrypt Firebase's AES encryption on their password hashes?

Tags: firebase, cryptography, aes

Firebase hashes user's passwords with what they call an "internally modified version of scrypt." In short, they first hash the plaintext passwords using the standard scrypt algorithm and then do rounds of AES to the hash. This is described in more detail in this thread: https://github.com/firebase/scrypt/issues/2

I've been able to reproduce Firebase's "modified version" and match the encrypted hashes exported from Firebase using Node's crypto module. The kicker is that **they flip the key and data inputs** so that the key is used as the message to encrypt and the hashed password is used as the key.

```
// Encryption
let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-ctr', **scryptHash**, iv)
let encrypted = cipher.update(**signerKey**, 'base64', 'base64')
encrypted += cipher.final('base64')

// This matches Firebase's exported password hashes
console.log("Firebase Custom Hash: ", encrypted)
```

When using cyrpto.createDecipheriv to decrypt the message, you have pass it the value of the key, but because the original key was actually the scrypt hash, we don't have this value.

The Point: Is it possible to decrypt the AES key if you have the decrypted data using the crypto module or any other library? If this is possible, it would allow us to import Firebase user's custom password hashes into other authentication systems that support standard scrypt.

Comment: That's not decryption, [**that's key recovery**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-recovery_attack). Because plaintext-ciphertext pairs can be obtained for most encryption systems, a cipher that allows key recovery is considered completely broken, insecure, worthless, and no one is allowed to use it. To your knowledge is anyone using AES? In fact, using a secret value to encrypt known (often fixed) data is a standard way to construct a one-way function i.e. a hash; the original Unix password hash 'descrypt' did _only_ that, although it used original-now-single DES which is now obsolete.

Comment: "Because plaintext-ciphertext pairs can be obtained for most encryption systems, a cipher that allows key recovery is considered completely broken"

That makes total sense. Sorry if this was a stupid question, but I've been learning a lot about cryptography as I've been trying to import these password hashes. Thanks for the explanation Dave!